# FtpWebRequest - Transferring file name containing fragment marker (#)

Tags: c#, ftpwebrequest

EDIT: Not sure its the answer but it is a workaround... rather than looking at the file transfer objects I added .Replace to the FTP string and got the result I was looking for, the target file name is now matching the source file name.

FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + targetServer + targetPath + fileInfo.Name.Replace("#", "%23"));

---

I have an existing C# FTP process that has been in use for years.  A new file naming convention was implemented that uses the # character in the actual file name.  From what I can tell the # is being interpreted as a fragment marker during the file transfer resulting in an incorrect file name on the target server.

Source file name: '9300T_#Test.xml'
Target file name: '9300T_'

Is there a way to force the actual file name to be used?

When I view object values during execution I can see the original string is correct but I also see the '#Test.xml' under the Fragment property.

I've experimented with different properties of WebRequest, FtpWebRequest, and Uri.  So far I have not found a combination that works and have not found a solution on the web.

I've tested using other FTP clients (DOS prompt, Mozilla) and the file is transferred correctly which leads me to believe the solution is property driven, or, it is a limitation to the objects I'm using.

Below is the code I'm testing from a windows form which produces the problem.

Thanks.

```
        string sourcePath = @"C:\FILES\";
        string sourcePattern = "9300T*.xml";
        string targetServer = "test_server_name";
        string targetPath = "/";
        string targetLogin = "server_login";
        string targetPassword = "login_password";

        string[] uploadFiles = Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, sourcePattern);

        // Loop through and process the list.
        foreach (string file in uploadFiles)
        {
            // Create the file information object.
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);

            // Create the FTP request object.
            FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + targetServer + targetPath + fileInfo.Name);
            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(targetLogin, targetPassword);
            ftpRequest.KeepAlive = false;
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
            ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
            ftpRequest.ContentLength = fileInfo.Length; 

            // Opens a file stream to read the file being uploaded.
            FileStream readStream = fileInfo.OpenRead();

            // Create the stream to which the upload file is written to.
            Stream writeStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();             // -- TARGET FILE IS CREATED WITH WRONG NAME AT THIS POINT

            // Set the buffer size.
            int bufferLength = 2048;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];

            // Read from and write to streams until content ends.
            int contentLength = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            while (contentLength != 0)
            {
                writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, contentLength);
                contentLength = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            }

            // Flush and close the streams.
            readStream.Flush();
            readStream.Close();

            writeStream.Flush();
            writeStream.Close();

            fileInfo.Delete();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are concatenating file name to create URL for web request,
you have to escape file name using [percent-enconding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), otherwise characters after "#" are considered to be [URL fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax) instead of being part of the file name.

I suggest to use function like `Uri.EscapeDataString()` Instead of `Replace("#", "%23")`, because it properly handles all other reserved characters (such as '@').

```
FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + targetServer + targetPath +  Uri.EscapeDataString(fileInfo.Name));
```

If *targetPath* could contain reserved characters, you may need to escape it too.

Comment: Thank you.  That is what I was looking for.  Much appreciated.